# RocketChat: Email authentication keeps failing

Tags: imap, rocket.chat, sttp

We have been trying for quite a while to connect our email server to the rocketchat, but we keep getting an authorisation mistake (see log below). It might have to do with the fact that in the form one has to add user and password but it’s not very clear user and password of what. We have tried all possible combinations we could think of, but we are kind of out of ideas. Suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Server Setup Information
Version of Rocket.Chat Server: CE 3.15.1
Operating System: ubuntu 20.04
Deployment Method: digitalocean IaaS
Number of Running Instances: 1

Log:
Exception in callback of async function: Error: Authentication failed. at Connection._resTagged (/opt/Rocket.Chat/programs/server/npm/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:1502:11) at Parser. (/opt/Rocket.Chat/programs/server/npm/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:194:10) at Parser.emit (events.js:314:20) at Parser.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12) at Parser._resTagged (/opt/Rocket.Chat/programs/server/npm/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:175:10) at Parser._parse (/opt/Rocket.Chat/programs/server/npm/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:139:16) at Parser._tryread (/opt/Rocket.Chat/programs/server/npm/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:82:15) at TLSSocket.Parser.cbReadable (/opt/Rocket.Chat/programs/server/npm/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:53:12) at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20) at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12) at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:557:12) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21) { type: ‘no’, textCode: ‘AUTHENTICATIONFAILED’, source: ‘authentication’ }

Comment: Well, it’s erroring in an imap module, therefore it’s looking for a username and password for the imap server you provided it.  I don’t know why it needs an imap account hough.

Comment: Yes, but I am puzzled. Rocketchat asks to provide user and password when registering the email. However it is not clear user and password of what. I have tried the SSH credentials, the email credentials and the RocketChat credentials. I have no clue what other combination I should try

Comment: What server is it contacting?  Presumably you had to give it an imap server to work with.  can you log into it with a regular email client?  If it's, for example, a gmail server, you're unlikely to be able to use plain IMAP authentication with it.

Comment: the mail is hosted at mail.wservices.ch

Comment: So privately hosted.  I would recommend setting up something like Thunderbird and make sure _you_ can access the server before trying to get it integrated into an app.  Do you have actually have email hosting configured at your host?

Comment: @Max yes, IMAP and SMTP are configured fine on the server. I do access the emails via Roundcube, but your saying I can't do this without a desktop IMAP client software?

Comment: RocketChat does manage to get to the IMAP server actually. Because now every time we receive an email to one of the registered email addresses RocketChat makes a new guest account in the contact list, if not already there. However, we don't see the email coming in

Comment: Possibly it's deleting it as soon as it processes it.  Sounds like it's working right then?

Comment: It seems like it stores the mail without opening it. I have disabled the automatic deletion. So if that is the only problem, I'd have to figure out the extra settings on RocketChat. However, I am not sure it's the all story, because the authentication error is still in the log. I think the error is at the RocketChat, not at the mail server. But I can't localise it.